# LayoutTransition Class in NineOldAndroids..?

Tags: android, animation, nineoldandroids

I want to animate add View as a "slide Down" and remove View as "slide Up" in a `ViewGroup`. So i used `LayoutTransition.class` but its not supported for `minSdk 8`. So i found this [NineOldAndroids](https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids),  and was wondering if i can achieve what i want using this.

Something like this,

```
LayoutTransition layoutTransition = new LayoutTransition();
        AnimatorSet set = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(getApplicationContext(),
                R.anim.slide);
        layoutTransition.setAnimator(LayoutTransition.APPEARING, set);
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately NineOldAndroids does not support LayoutTransitions as it is not possible to implement in Gingerbread.

Answer (score 0):

I also need to animate when adding a view without LayoutTransition. 
I have no idea when to start the animation so I use LayoutAnimationController to do
:

```
     // A fake AlphaAnimation so that we can know how to start the animation of adding view
      Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0, 0);
        animation.setDuration(1);
        animation.setFillAfter(true);
        animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }
```

`@Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
           // start the animation here
           startAddingViewAnimation();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
   ViewGroup viewroot = findViewById(R.id.viewroot);
   LayoutAnimationController layoutAnimationController = new LayoutAnimationController(animation);
    viewRoot.setLayoutAnimation(layoutAnimationController);    
    viewRoot.addView(btn);`

Set a LayoutAnimationController to notify me that the view was added and finished to draw. Then I can start the animation by nineoldanimator.